# Handling 404 errors in Coldfusion 8 with onMissingTemplate() not working

Tags: coldfusion, error-handling, http-status-code-404, application.cfc

I am trying to handle 404 errors in my ColdFusion app with onMissingTemplate() method in Application.cfc.

My dev environment is ColdFusion 8 (dev edition) + JRun + Linux. In [web_root]/testmissing/Application.cfc I have code from CF docs:

```
<cfcomponent>

    <cffunction name="onMissingTemplate">
        <cfargument name="targetPage" type="string" required=true/>

        <!--- Use a try block to catch errors. --->
        <cftry>
            <!--- Log all errors. --->
            <cflog type="error" text="Missing template: #Arguments.targetPage#">

            <!--- Display an error message. --->
            <cfoutput>
                <h3>#Arguments.targetPage# could not be found.</h2>
                <p>You requested a non-existent ColdFusion page.<br />
                Please check the URL.</p>
            </cfoutput>

            <cfreturn true />

            <!--- If an error occurs, return false and the default error
            handler will run. --->
            <cfcatch>
                <cfreturn false />
            </cfcatch>
        </cftry>

    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

When I browse /testmissing/foo.cfm I get default CF "File not found:..." error page.

I tried the same code on different environment: Coldfusion 9 (dev edition) + Apache + Windows. Browsing /testmissing/foo.cfm resulted in custome error message from onMissingTemplate, as expected.

This proves the code is ok and the problem is somewhere in my dev environment, but I can't find it. Any ideas why I am still getting the default CF error page?

Answer (score 0):

How are your Error Handlers setup in your CF Administrator?  Compare between your CF8 and CF9 environments.

Comment: They are empty in both CF8 and CF9 environments. Production server is shared among other CF apps and I don't want to catch their 404 errors. So I am trying to handle 404s on application level.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without the try/catch in there? Just want to make sure you're not obscuring an issue with cflog.

Comment: Yes, I tried without try/catch block first, but without luck. I have noticed a strange behaviour. If is put in URL only /testmissing/ than onMissingTemplate() gets triggered (I don't have the index file in testmissing). However, /testmissing/foo.cfm or anythig else dosn't trigger onMissingTemplate(). I had to give up and solve it via rewrite rules on the server side :|